# convert data obtained from influxdb to JSON

Tags: json, go, influxdb

This is the first time I use `go` and first time I encounter `influxdb`.
I am using this lib:

```
"github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client/v2"
```

After much tinkering, I finally can query `influxdb` and get the data as below:

```
[{[{sampledata map[] [time x y z] 
[
    [2020-12-23T21:39:49Z -0.011 0.0128 0.0117] 
    [2020-12-23T21:39:48Z 0.0089 -0.0242 -0.0011] 
    [2020-12-23T21:39:47Z 0.026 0.0211 0.0058]
] 
false}][]}]
```

I tried many ways to convert it to either `json` or `string` or `[]byte` by typecast them, but it always give me the error message `cannot use data (variable of type client.Result) as []byte value in argument`, which `client.Result` is the type from the `influxdb/client/v2`.

How can I convert the `client.Result` to any of the type that is useful in my case? I need to send the data out via `web socket`, so I need it to be in `[]byte`.

**UPDATE1**

I found [this link from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165226/how-to-process-result-obtained-from-querying-influxdb-database-from-go-code). Will try to implement this and try to understand how it works.

Comment: You're not "getting the data as below"; ostensibly what you have put in your question is how some function from the `fmt` package have rendered (as text) a complex `struct`-typed value you have obtained from influxdb. Hence, as stated, the question is unanswerable: please show what exact type is used for both the value and for all its fields (recursively, if needed).

Comment: …and while we're at it, have you already tried passing your value to `encoding/json.Marshal`? May be there is no problem to solve using StackOverflow?

Comment: @kostix i tried to `Marshal` but it keep giving me the `type` error. I just updated my error. I read about using empty `interface{}` but that will just convert that variable into `client.Result`, which I still cannot use it in any way.

Comment: Did you try to interpret "cannot use data (variable of type client.Result) as []byte value in argument" literally? I mean, there is no magic in this sentence: it says to you that you have tried to call (some function, you did not tell us which one it was) and pass a value of type `client.Result` for one of the function's arguments which is defined to accept values of type `[]byte` (which obviously did not work). From where I stand, [`json.Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) did not even have an argument of type `[]byte`, so I'm not sure what you have tried to call.

Comment: @kostix I understand what you mean. I spend the whole day reading and testing the query data and the link i posted give me some idea how i can tackle this problem. I will update more when I have something more fruitful.

Comment: Any update there dude? Having the same issue with influx 1.x old go-client.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem for json or struct but only find key,value.
here is my code if could help you.

```
// Create a new client using an InfluxDB server base URL and an authentication token
client := influxdb2.NewClient("http://localhost:8086", token)
defer client.Close()

query := fmt.Sprintf("from(bucket:\"%v\")|> range(start: %v) |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == \"%v\")", bucket, from, measurement)
// Get query client
queryAPI := client.QueryAPI(org)
// get QueryTableResult
result, err := queryAPI.Query(context.Background(), query)
if err == nil {
    // Iterate over query response
    for result.Next() {
        // Access data
        fmt.Printf("%v : %v\n", result.Record().Field(), result.Record().Value())
    }
    // check for an error
    if result.Err() != nil {
        log.Printf("query parsing error: %v\n", result.Err().Error())
    }
} else {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: He was asking about influx 1.x, what you are suggesting is `influxdb2-client-go`

Comment: my friend, he uses the v2 library. why do you think it's 1.x?

Comment: because the import url that shared is used to be for influx 1.x.

Comment: v2 doesn't mean its 2.x because still now 1.x has this import url `github.com/influxdata/influxdb1-client/v2"`